# convenience-layer for std::algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

I'm tiered of writing

```
void no_fun(std::vector<int> & vec)
{
     std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(),my_comp);
}
```

I want to write something like this

```
void fun(std::vector<int> & vec)
{
     std::sort(vec,my_comp);
}
```

**Question**
How can i achieve that

**What i tried so far**

```
namespace std
{

template<typename T>
void sort(std::vector<T> & vec)
{
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
}

template<typename T, class Compare >
void sort(std::vector<T>& vec, Compare comp)
{
    sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), comp);
}

}
```

I tested it with Visual Studio 2013 but it doesn't work

Comment: You should not add anything to the `std` namespace.

Comment: It isn't allowed to add functions or function overloads to `namespace std`, but you can put these functions outside this namespace. In any case, you should clarify what errors you get as "doesn't work" doesn't tell us much.

Comment: Use the ranges library

Comment: from [namespace.std]: The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it adds declarations or definitions to namespace std or to a
namespace within namespace std unless otherwise specified.

Comment: You could try the [`boost.range` algorithms](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_60_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/algorithms/mutating/sort.html).

Comment: There is also [range v3](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) which is going to be made into a TS: http://ericniebler.com/2014/11/07/ranges-concepts-and-the-future-of-the-standard-library/

Comment: Is the namespace the only problem? does it work if use another namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, your `no_fun()` should really take pair of iterators (aka range) and not a container reference. The reason why there are still no ranges in C++, and why containers are not implicitly converted to those ranges where appropriate is out of question here. Apart from this, one thing you might want to do is define a macro like

```
using std::begin;
using std::end;    
#define ALL(c) begin(c), end(c)
```

Then you can write

```
std::sort(ALL(your_vec));
```

Just be sure to not put it in a header file.

Comment: why not putting it in a header?

Comment: It is not because something will get immidiately broken if you do. But you pollute the global namespace and one day it may bite you back

Comment: @user1235183 Because if you pollute the global namespace with a 3-letter macro, insanity will ensue. This is a fair warning :)

Comment: Solving this problem with this macro is like fixing a broken elbow by chopping off the arm.